# Transferring ownership in GDrive per Script

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions, google-drive-api

When I use my script to transfer ownership of a folder it moves the folder to the new owner's "shared with me drive" instead of "My drive".

```js
function myChangeOwnerCreateList() {
    var myfolders = DriveApp.searchFolders('"me" in owners');

    let toOwner = "max.mustermann@google.com";
   
    while (myfolders.hasNext()) {
      var folder = myfolders.next();
      var myName = folder.getName();
      var myID = folder.getId();
      var myURL = folder.getUrl();
      Logger.log(myName)
      folder.addEditor(toOwner);
      folder.setOwner(toOwner);
    }
}
```

The owner is set correctly, only the new owner cannot see the files immediately because they are under "Shared with me".

Where is my bug?

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that your script is creating an orphan folder. IMHO this is a Google Drive bug as per default files and folders should have the user's root as the default folder.

As a regular user, you can't add folder to other user root. Consider to send a email to the new owner suggesting to move the orphan files and folders to their "My Drive".

Related

- [How to view orphans in Google Drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/74793/88163)
- [File not showing on "Shared with me", even with a Apps Script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/167152/88163)